# C# Access types in another Form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a Form1 and Form2, both are active and running and I can change values on both at the same time and want to Access (read and write) a boolean and integer in active Form1 from active Form2.

Now I've read that there are multiple ways to approach that and I wonder which one would be the *best* and easiest to use?

1: Declaring boolean as static in Form1:

```
//Form2
if(MyProject.Form1.boolean1 = true)
{
    MyProject.Form1.integer1 = 2;
}

//Form1
public static bool boolean1 = true;
public static int integer1 = 1; //changes to 2
```

2: Declaring public variales

```
//Form2
private Form1 form1 = new Form1();
if(form1.boolean1 = true)
{
    form1.integer1 = 2;
}

//Form1
private bool boolean1 = true;
public bool Boolean1
{
    get
    {
        return this.boolean1;
    }
}

private int integer1 = 1;
public int Integer1
{
    get
    {
        return this.integer1;
    }
    set
    {
        this.integer1 = value;
    }
}
```

3: Initialize Form

```
//Form2
private Form1 form1 = new Form1();

 if(form1.boolean1 = true)
{
   form1.integer1 = 2;
}

//Form1
public bool boolean1 = true;
public int integer1 = 1; //changes to 2
```

4: Direct Initialize

```
 //Form2
if(new Form1().boolean1 = true)
{
   new Form1().integer1 = 2;
}

//Form1
public bool boolean1 = true;
public int integer1 = 1; //changes to 2
```

If I initialize a Form1 as new Form does that mean it will create a new form and doesn't use the already changed values from my active Form1 but uses the default static int and bool values from Form1?

How could I get around that and are there better ways than the methods above?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Initializing new forms doesn't use the already created instance. It's a **new** form. You can have a field in one form to hold the instance of the other.

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate use of `static`.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb hey thanks for your answer, thats what i thought. How could I approach that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go the static route, as the variable clearly belongs to the form.

I don't know what you are trying with both the initalisation routes, but they are also not right.

So that leaves only the public properties way.  But you can simplify your code, and here you have no need for them to have private backed fields.

```
// The get is public, but the set can only be used within Form1
public bool Boolean1 { get; private set; }  

//    
public int Integer1 {get; set;}
```